# OrbitControls of THREE.js displaying error

Tags: angular, three.js, 3d

I have already installed THREE.js in my angular project.I am trying to use OrbitControls in the below fashion but it is giving an error:-

```
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(this.camera,this.renderer.domElement);
```

The error is :

```
Property 'OrbitControls' does not exist on type 'typeof import.
```

Can anybody suggest how to use OrbitControl in angular project?

I tried to install the below npm libraries but without luck :-

```
npm i @types/three --save-dev 
npm i --save three-orbit-controls
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package three-orbit-controls has been deprecated.

Try with :

```
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";
```